# Share USB port for scanner between Ubuntu and Windows 10 through virtual box 7.0

Tags: usb, virtualbox, scanner

I bought an IRIScan 5 hoping I could use it through VBM 7.0, but this more complicated than expected.

In Ubuntu, the device is detected:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ lsusb
...
Bus XXX Device XXX: ID XXXX:XXXX Microdia USB 2.0 Hub
...// a total of 11 devices
```

But in Windows 10, through VM VirtualBox 7.0, this is not detected at all:

```
PS C:\Users\Ave> Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' }
Status     Class           Friendlyname                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
OK         HIDClass        Périphérique d’entrée USB                                                        USB\VID_80EE... 
OK         USB             Concentrateur USB racine                                                         USB\ROOT_HUB... 
OK         USB             Concentrateur USB racine                                                         USB\ROOT_HUB...
// a total of 3 devices
```

About settings In VBM 7.0: I checked `Enable USB controller`.

UPDATE

Addons (gest/usb) were already installed in the Windows 10 virtual machine, so the problem was not from there.

About `vboxusers` in Ubuntu. I checked if it exists and it does. I checked if my user `avy` is into it, and it does:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ getent group vboxusers
vboxusers:x:000:avy
```

I reboot Ubuntu ([necessity in my OS version according to csoring](https://superuser.com/a/957636)), and now it works for the sharing (only):

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ VBoxManage list usbhost
UUID:               XXXX
VendorId:           0x0c45 (0C45)
ProductId:          0x0800 (0800)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               2
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       Mysher
Product:            IRIScan Desk 5
SerialNumber:       SN0001
Address:            XXX
Current State:      Captured
```

The problem for driver recognition seems to come from Windows 10 now.
It clearly complain about the driver "USB Unknown, State: Driver's error". I did not have this problem on other Windows computer, so the problem is not from hardware.

Comment: install guest addons & usb. then goto vbox settings then usb then add a new usb &save.

Comment: @petep, thanks I checked, it's alright about sharing USB peripherals. My main issue now is Windows VM don't recognize this peripheral (while it does for others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the way to make it work through Oracle Virtual Box.

1. First, check if your user is in the group of `vboxusers` through the command `getent group vboxusers`. If this is not the case, add it through the command `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers`. [You must reboot the OS to make it effective](https://superuser.com/a/957636).
2. Check if Ubuntu and your VM share USB through the command `VBoxManage list usbhost`. It should give you a list where IRIScan device appears notably.
3. According to the VM's version, you must use "pack extension". [Here a tutorial (FR)](https://www.numetopia.fr/comment-activer-le-support-usb-2-ou-3-dans-virtualbox/) I was based on. In my case that was not necessary because my version is 7.
4. In virtual machine settings, check "Enable USB controller" and click on the radio button "[USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller](https://superuser.com/a/1401713)". Other controllers proposed failed for me.
5. Now boot your VM. Go through the tabs Devices > USB > IRIScan Desk 5, and check it.
6. Then you can use it as camera (exactly like a webcam). If you installed the software IRIScan Desk, you can use it to scan through this.